# Why does MongoEngine Document accepts undefined fields without raising an Exception?

Tags: python, mongoengine

If I have a MongoEngine Document and if I make an instance of it supplying undefined fields, it doesn't raise an exception. Why is this? I would like to know when I supply an undefined field.

```
MyDoc(undefined_field='test').save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the feeling this is missing functionality from MongoEngine so I created a pull request:

https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/pull/457

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of using MongoDB is to be flexible in schema, and hence they are said to be schemaless. The frameworks allows the functionality to be useful, by allowing adding non defined fields.

I am not sure about MongoEngine, but if you are using mongokit, we can specify not to be strict to our schema, otherwise ValidationError will be raised by default.
To make it schemaless, we add use_schemaless = True in Document class, to make it schemaless.

I would prefer to use MongoKit over MongoEngine, not just because of this reason, but of the fact that, MongoEngine adds extra fields and attributes into your data when the same is saved 
in DB. If you would rather like your data to be clean, please go for MongoKit(Just an advice from previous experience). You can refer here: [mongokit](http://namlook.github.io/mongokit/).

Thanks!

Comment: The undefined fields won't get added to the database, so it's quite useless. Also, from the MongoEngine docs: "However, defining schemata for our documents can help to iron out bugs involving incorrect types or missing fields, and also allow us to define utility methods on our documents in the same way that traditional ORMs do." (http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#defining-our-documents)

Comment: Agree with you bro. Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks but I quite like MongoEngine besides this issue. I created a pull request to remedy this issue.